# How to Create PHP rest api for uploading files from any device?

Tags: php, api, file-upload, server, rest

I am creating an API to register a user. I'm successfully able to register but the image is not uploading.
I make some searches on google and got some info about file_put_contet() but don't know the right way to implement it

```
 <?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Acess-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Acess-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Acess-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Content-Type,Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Authorization');

$data=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);

    $p_name=$data['p_name'];
    $gaurdian=$data['gaurdian'];
    $document=$data['document'];
    $card_no=$data['card_no'];
    $state=$data['state'];
    $district=$data['district'];
    $village=$data['village'];
    $pin=$data['pin'];
    $phone=$data['phone'];
    $email=$data['email'];
    $gender=$data['gender'];
    $t_name=$data['team_name'];

    $passport_photo = $_FILES['photo1']['name'];
    $temp_name1=$_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'];
    $size1=$_FILES['photo1']['size'];
    $type1=$_FILES['photo1']['type'];

    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$passport_photo)));
    $ext=array("jpeg","jpg","png");

    if(in_array($file_ext,$ext) === false){
        echo'<script>alert("This file type is not allowed, please choose a jpg or png")</script>';
    }

    if($size1 > 50000){
        echo'<script>alert("File size must be 150kb")</script>';
        die();
    }

    $path = "images/passport_photo/".$passport_photo;


    $card_photo=$_FILES['photo2']['name'];
    $temp_name2=$_FILES['photo2']['tmp_name'];
    $size2=$_FILES['photo2']['size'];
    $type2=$_FILES['photo2']['type'];

    $file_ext1=strtolower(end(explode('.',$card_photo)));
    $ext1=array("jpeg","jpg","png","pdf");

    if(in_array($file_ext1,$ext1) === false){
        echo'<script>alert("This file type is not allowed, please choose a jpg, png or pdf file.")</script>';
        die();
    }

    if($size2 > 150000){
        echo'<script>alert("File size must be 150kb")</script>';
        die();
    }

    $path1 = "images/document_photo/".$card_photo;

        if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name1,$path) && move_uploaded_file($temp_name2,$path1)){

            echo $query="INSERT INTO `player_reg` (`age_category`, `player_name`, `gaurdian_name`, `doc_type`, `card_no`, `state`, `district`, `town`,`pincode`, `image`, `doc_img`, `phone`, `email`, `gender`, `sport`, `team_name`,`date`) VALUES ('{$_SESSION["age_cat"]}','{$p_name}','{$gaurdian}','{$document}','{$card_no}','{$state}','{$district}','{$village}','{$pin}','{$passport_photo}','{$card_photo}','{$phone}','{$email}','{$gender}','{$_SESSION ['sport_type']}','{$t_name}','{$date}')";
            $output=mysqli_query($con,$query);

            if($output){
            
            redirect("team-reg.php");
        }
    }


    $query="INSERT INTO `player_reg` (`age_category`, `player_name`, `gaurdian_name`, `doc_type`, `card_no`, `state`, `district`, `town`,`pincode`, `image`, `doc_img`, `phone`, `email`, `gender`, `sport`, `team_name`,`date`) VALUES ('{$_SESSION["age_cat"]}','{$p_name}','{$gaurdian}','{$document}','{$card_no}','{$state}','{$district}','{$village}','{$pin}','{$passport_photo}','{$card_photo}','{$phone}','{$email}','{$gender}','{$_SESSION ['sport_type']}','{$t_name}','{$date}')";
                $output=mysqli_query($con,$query);

                if($output){
                
                    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'User registered successfully!','status' => true));
            }

?>
```

The user is registered successfully but the image is not uploading to the server.

Answer (score 0):

To upload an image using API, the most suitable method is to pass base64 encoded image data in Json request, then decode the base64 encoded string into file using `file_put_contents()`.

```
$img_info = explode(',',$data['photo']);

$image_content = base64_decode($img_info[1]);

$img_extension = substr($img_info[0], 11, 3);

$img_filename = "images/passport_photo/some_random_text".$img_extension;

file_put_contents($img_filename, $image_content);
//apply your filters of size, extensions before uploading the image
```

But base64 is not a good idea to upload large size images.
First of all Upload image and then pass the image URL in json request.